# How to send local usernotifications based on user input

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, nsusernotification, unnotificationtrigger

How am I able to send user notifications in iOS 10 using UNNotifications on a specific day and repeat it?

The user has the option to select a few days when he wants to receive the notifications:

[image]

If the user selects for example: Tuesday, Thursday, Sunday he needs to receive them on these days.

Can anybody help me out with that?

Kind Regards,

**Solution:**
    import UIKit
    import UserNotifications

```
class workoutNotificationVC: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var mondayBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tuesdayBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var wednesdayBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var thursdayBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var fridayBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var saturdayBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sundayBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmNotification: UIButton!

    // Vars
    var isSelectedMonday = false
    var isSelectedTuesday = false
    var isSelectedWednesday = false
    var isSelectedThursday = false
    var isSelectedFriday = false
    var isSelectedSaturday = false
    var isSelectedSunday = false

    var dayIntegers = [Int]()
    var workoutNotificationsDays = [String]()
    var parentVC: CustomTabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    }

    // IBAction
    @IBAction func mondayBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if isSelectedMonday == true {
            isSelectedMonday = false
            mondayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            isSelectedMonday = true
            mondayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked"), for: .normal)
            dayIntegers.append(2)
            workoutNotificationsDays.append("Maandag")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func tuesdayBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if isSelectedTuesday == true {
            isSelectedTuesday = false
            tuesdayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            isSelectedTuesday = true
            tuesdayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked"), for: .normal)
            dayIntegers.append(3)
            workoutNotificationsDays.append("Dinsdag")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func wednesdayBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if isSelectedWednesday == true {
            isSelectedWednesday = false
            wednesdayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            isSelectedWednesday = true
            wednesdayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked"), for: .normal)
            dayIntegers.append(4)
            workoutNotificationsDays.append("Woensdag")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func thursdayBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if isSelectedThursday == true {
            isSelectedThursday = false
            thursdayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            isSelectedThursday = true
            thursdayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked"), for: .normal)
            dayIntegers.append(5)
            workoutNotificationsDays.append("Donderdag")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func fridayBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if isSelectedFriday == true {
            isSelectedFriday = false
            fridayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            isSelectedFriday = true
            fridayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked"), for: .normal)
            dayIntegers.append(6)
            workoutNotificationsDays.append("Vrijdag")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func saturdayBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if isSelectedSaturday == true {
            isSelectedSaturday = false
            saturdayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            isSelectedSaturday = true
            saturdayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked"), for: .normal)
            dayIntegers.append(7)
            workoutNotificationsDays.append("Zaterdag")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sundayBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if isSelectedSunday == true {
            isSelectedSunday = false
            sundayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            isSelectedSunday = true
            sundayBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked"), for: .normal)
            dayIntegers.append(1)
            workoutNotificationsDays.append("Zondag")
        }
    }

    func sendNotificationTest() {
        // Check what days were selected and send notifications on these days
        for day in dayIntegers {
            if day == 1 {
                print("Je wilt een notificatie op Zondag")

                // Send the notifcation at a specific time or date
                var dateComponents = DateComponents()
                dateComponents.weekday = 1
                dateComponents.hour = 9
                dateComponents.minute = 0

                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                let requestIdentifier = "Sunday Notification"

                content.title = "We are missing you"
                content.subtitle = "You received 100 coins for Sunday"
                content.body = "Your Notification for Sunday "
                content.badge = 1

                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)


                // create request
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in

                    if (error != nil) {
                        print("there was an error with the notification")
                    }else{
                        print("we have sent your notification on Sunday!")
                    }
                })
            }else if day == 2 {
                print("Je wilt een notificatie op Maandag")

                // Send the notifcation at a specific time or date
                var dateComponents = DateComponents()
                dateComponents.weekday = 2
                dateComponents.hour = 9
                dateComponents.minute = 0

                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                let requestIdentifier = "Monday Notification"

                content.title = "We are missing you"
                content.subtitle = "You received 100 coins for Monday"
                content.body = "Your Notification for Monday "
                content.badge = 1

                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)


                // create request
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in

                    if (error != nil) {
                        print("there was an error with the notification")
                    }else{
                        print("we have sent your notification on Monday!")
                    }
                })
            }else if day == 3 {
                print("Je wilt een notificatie op Dinsdag")
                // Send the notifcation at a specific time or date
                var dateComponents = DateComponents()
                dateComponents.weekday = 3
                dateComponents.hour = 9
                dateComponents.minute = 0

                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                let requestIdentifier = "Tuesday Notification"

                content.title = "We are missing you"
                content.subtitle = "You received 54 coins for Tuesday"
                content.body = "Your Notification for Tuesday "
                content.badge = 1

                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)


                // create request
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in

                    if (error != nil) {
                        print("there was an error with the notification")
                    }else{
                        print("we have sent your notification on Tuesday!")
                    }
                })
            }else if day == 4 {
                print("Je wilt een notificatie op Woensdag")
                // Send the notifcation at a specific time or date
                var dateComponents = DateComponents()
                dateComponents.weekday = 4
                dateComponents.hour = 9
                dateComponents.minute = 0

                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                let requestIdentifier = "Wednesday Notification"

                content.title = "We are missing you"
                content.subtitle = "You received 1000000 coins for Wednesday"
                content.body = "Your Notification for Wednesday "
                content.badge = 1

                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

                // create request
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in

                    if (error != nil) {
                        print("there was an error with the notification")
                    }else{
                        print("we have sent your notification on wednesday!")
                    }
                })
            }else if day == 5 {
                print("Je wilt een notificatie op Donderdag")
                // Send the notifcation at a specific time or date
                var dateComponents = DateComponents()
                dateComponents.weekday = 5
                dateComponents.hour = 9
                dateComponents.minute = 0

                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                let requestIdentifier = "Thursday Notification"

                content.title = "We are missing you"
                content.subtitle = "You received zero coins for Thursday"
                content.body = "Your Notification for Thursday "
                content.badge = 1

                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

                // create request
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in

                    if (error != nil) {
                        print("there was an error with the notification")
                    }else{
                        print("we have sent your notification on Thursday!")
                    }
                })
            }else if day == 6 {
                print("Je wilt een notificatie op Vrijdag")
                // Send the notifcation at a specific time or date
                var dateComponents = DateComponents()
                dateComponents.weekday = 6
                dateComponents.hour = 9
                dateComponents.minute = 0

                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                let requestIdentifier = "Friday Notification"

                content.title = "We are missing you"
                content.subtitle = "You received some coins for Friday"
                content.body = "Your Notification for Friday "
                content.badge = 1

                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)


                // create request
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in

                    if (error != nil) {
                        print("there was an error with the notification")
                    }else{
                        print("we have sent your notification on Friday!")
                    }
                })
            }else if day == 7 {
                print("Je wilt een notificatie op Zaterdag")
                // Send the notifcation at a specific time or date
                var dateComponents = DateComponents()
                dateComponents.weekday = 7
                dateComponents.hour = 9
                dateComponents.minute = 0

                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                let requestIdentifier = "Saturday Notification"

                content.title = "We are missing you"
                content.subtitle = "You received some Really nice coins for Saturday"
                content.body = "Your Notification for Saturday "
                content.badge = 1

                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)


                // create request
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in

                    if (error != nil) {
                        print("there was an error with the notification")
                    }else{
                        print("we have sent your notification on Saturday!")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }


    // shows notificatins in app
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        // reset icon badge number to no notification when opened
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        // shows the notification in app
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }


    @IBAction func confirmNotificationBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        sendNotificationTest()
        // we have send the notifications to the users days
    }
}
```

Comment: @matt can you tell me how I am able to send the notification based on the what the user selected?

Comment: Look at what the user selected and obey. What's the problem?

Comment: @matt I will update my question with the code I have working now. The problem is that it is isn't nice code. It needs to be refactored but how can I make this code more reusable?